# Git push only certain files to production branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I am somewhat new to Git, so I'm still nailing the workflow down. Basically, I think I'm going to use two master branches. One to hold ALL my dev files (Master), and one to only hold the files needed for production on the server (Production). So the structure looks like this.

```
Me - Commits - Master Branch - Production Branch
```

However, not all files need to be on the Production branch. So I there are a few things I am trying to figure out... The first of which, how do I limit which files get pushed to the production branch?

```
.
├── master.py
├── presets.py
|   ├── preset1.py
|   └── preset2.py
├── other_scripts
|   ├── something.sh
|   └── somethingelse.sh
├── test.py *
├── Instal.md *
```

So for instance, the items with * are not needed in production. How do I exclude them? And further more, would I want to do a pull/clone FROM master to production, or a push TO production?

Any workflow tips would be great! Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use GIT as your deployment strategy. I dont recommend this, as that isn't what GIT is for. There are better tools to use for deployment of software.

Comment: Look into TeamCity

Answer (score 0):

When you checkout a branch, the folder contains the files of this branch, and only them. So just checkout the branch you would like to work on, create/edit files, add them, commit them, and they are part of this branch (not the other one).

Then you can checkout the other branch. The content of the folder changes and these other files “disappeared” because they are not part of this branch. Create/edit other files, add them, commit them and they will be part of this branch (not the other one).

When you merge a branch, you can cherry pick the files you would like to take. In this case, just pick the ones you would like to keep in your master branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can add all entries in `.gitignore` file, If you do not have this file go to your git repo directory and run this `touch .gitignore`.

Add entries to be ignored in this file, a sample of entry in this file is

```
# compiled output
    /dist
    /tmp

    # dependencies
    /node_modules

    # IDEs and editors
    /.idea
    .project
    .classpath
    .c9/
    *.launch
    .settings/
```

All these files and directories will be ignored while commiting

Answer (score 0):

You can remove appropriate files (only if already added).
If the files you do not need are staged, you can execute this command:

```
git rm --cached test.py Install.md
```

to unstage them and then:

```
git add master.py presets.py other_scripts
git commit -m "Only needed files."
git push productionBranch
```

If you think you will never need to push those files to any branch, you can add their names to `.gitignore`:

```
presets.py
other_scripts
```